# Using Php, mySql, ajax, (xmlhttp) and JS,how can i create a php multidimensional send it to JS and use it?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli, xmlhttprequest

I looked a lot on the internet and wasn't able to find the answer i need, so here i come to you.
**What i have :** A database which look like this :

```
name  latitude  longitude
---- --------- ----------
foo    13.323   -51.356
foo    54.698   2.487
```

**What i want to do :** I need to retrieve the latitude and longitude from a mysqli request done with php and use it in a function that i defined.

**My problem :** I'm trying to use xmlrequest but it apparently doesn't work.

**The code :** JS :

```
var selI = document.getElementById("nameIti");    
selI.onchange = function(){
                var val = this[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute("value");
                showMark(val);
            }
function showMark(str){
            var xhr;
            if(str==""){
                return;
            }
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else{
                xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status ==200){
                    var object = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    for(var a in object){
                    newMark(v['lat'], v['lng']);
                    document.getElementById("pi").innerHTML=JSON.parse(xrh.responseText); // This is a test to display any kind of result.
                    }                       
                }
            }
            xhr.open("GET", "getpos.php?q="+str, true);
            xhr.send();
        }
```

PHP :

```
<?php
$nom = $_GET['q'];

include("connexion.php");
$con = connect_LIF4();
$req1= "SELECT Latitude, Longitude FROM etape LEFT JOIN itineraires ON NomLieu=nomEtape WHERE nomIti LIKE '%$nom%'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $req1);

$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1){
    $data['lat'] = $row['Latitude'];
    $data['lng'] = $row['Longitude'];
    $resp[] = $data;
}
echo json_encode($resp);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I tried to use newMark(lat, lng)(Which i coded and works fine) with random values, in showMark outside the onreadystatechange and it works, but i need to use it with the values retrieved from the php.

Comment: Can you use Jquery? Ajax call are a little semplified

Comment: Perhaps the problem is you need to use the full url instead of just getpos.php?

Comment: getpos.php is in the same directory than my JS. And ... How do I know if i can use Jquery...? :x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with your PHP is that

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1){
```

is missing the second brace. It should be:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
```

Also the URL in the ajax request should be the full URL, not just getpos.php

Thirdly you have written xrh.responseText (should be xhr).

Basically there's loads of syntax errors in your code - you should use the javascript console to debug the front end ones, and PHP logging or error display for the back end ones. You should only need help here once you've debugged all obvious syntax errors.

**EDIT - below is a working example (although I haven't done the MySQL part)**

JS + HTML:

```
<span id='pi'></span>
<select id='nameIti'>
    <option value='foo'>foo</option>
    <option value='bar'>bar</option>
</select>

<script>

function newMark(lat,lng) {
    console.log(lat);
    console.log(lng);
}

var selI = document.getElementById("nameIti");
selI.onchange = function(){
                var val = this[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute("value");
                showMark(val);
            }

function showMark(val){

    var str=val;
    var xhr;
    // if(str==""){
    //     return;
    // }
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status ==200){
            var result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(result);
            for(var a in result){
                newMark(result[a]['lat'], result[a]['lng']);
                document.getElementById("pi").innerHTML = result[a]['lat'] + ', ' + result[a]['lng'];
            }
        }
    }
    // xhr.open("GET", "getpos.php?q="+str, true);
    xhr.open("GET", "getpos.php?q="+str, true);
    xhr.send();
}
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$nom = $_GET['q'];

$data = array();
if($nom == 'foo') {
  $data['lat'] = '5.12';
  $data['lng'] = '0.34';
  $resp[] = $data;
}
else if($nom == 'bar') {
  $data['lat'] = '2.34';
  $data['lng'] = '1.34';
  $resp[] = $data;
}
echo json_encode($resp);
?>
```

Comment: Even if getpos.php is in the same directory than my JS?

Comment: Yes you're right if it's in the same directory then it should be ok as it is. However see my other comments, there's loads of syntax errors in your code that should come up in the JS console and PHP error logs / display. Fix these first.

Comment: Well, you're right, but my problem is xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){ which do not enter the "if" and i can't explain why.

Comment: That may be because there's an error in getpos.php which means a different status code will be returned (ie. not 200). Try going to getpos.php?q=whatever in your browser and see if you get any errors.

Comment: Oddly, the JS console pointed out it can't find getpos.php even if it's in the same directory than the JS, but I resolved that, and now I get a : too much recurtion error. I don't understand none of my function call themselves.

Comment: Thanks you a lot, it was the right spelling of newMark(result[a]['lat'], result[a]['lng']); i missed ><.

Comment: Yes also your for...in loop was wrong. The var before the in - 'a' in this case is just an identifier, so you can't do a['lat'], as you were trying. You have to do result[a]['lat'].